# in laravel if condition not working in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i am trying to use if condition in controller ( IF IMAGE NOT UPLOADED it go to ELSE condition Or else go to IF    )  but it was not working , it just redirecting  registration from page when submitting a form

**code**

```
public function Enrollment(Request $request)

{

  $this->validate($request, [

      'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'father_name' => 'required|string|max:225',
      'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'card_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',

    ]);

    if ($request->image != '')


  {


    $input['name'] = strtoupper ($request['name']);
    $input['father_name'] = strtoupper ($request['father_name']);
    $input['address'] = strtoupper ($request['address']);
    $input['card_id'] = strtoupper ($request['card_id']);

    $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $folder1 = public_path('IMAGE/');
    $path1 = $folder1 . $input['image']; // path 1
    $request->image->move($folder1, $input['image']); // image saved in first folder
    $path2 = public_path('IMAGE/BACKUP_IMAGE/') . $input['image']; // path 2
    \File::copy($path1, $path2);



}else{

    $input['name'] = strtoupper ($request['name']);
    $input['father_name'] = strtoupper ($request['father_name']);
    $input['address'] = strtoupper ($request['address']);
    $input['card_id'] = strtoupper ($request['card_id']);


   }

    Card::create($input);

   return back()->with('success','Enrolled Successfully.');
}
```

Comment: try this `if(!empty($request->image)) { //your code here }` or `if(!empty($request->input('image'))) { //your code here }`

Comment: @mafortis not working

Comment: before validator put this code and add results to your question so we can see what actually you receive `dd($request->all());`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($request->hasfile('user_image'))
```

Comment: Why should OP try this? What was wrong with the code, what did you change?

Answer (score 0):

Nice that you use laravel. At first I will give you some hints to improve your code snippet.

You've written

> it just redirecting registration from page when submitting a form

that's correct, because if you submit the form without an image, the validation will say "false".

You can't check an required in this way:

> if ($request->image != '')   {

because it's required.

Actually your code skips the validation at all, it would be better if you use the following:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'father_name' => 'required|string|max:225',
    'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'card_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    Session::flash('error', $validator->messages()->first());
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

If you dump your dd($validator); you will see all opertunities to validate the $request. Your errors you will find here: $validator->errors().

If something went wrong you should redirect back with the

> ->withInput()

so all data will stay in the form. Also possible with some explanation for the user ->withErrors():

```
    // message information for the user
    $messages = $validator->errors();
    $messages->add('Your explanation'); 

    // redirect
    return redirect()->route('index')->withErrors($messages)->withInput();
```

Actually I am unsure why you save all $request in $input.

You can check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#using-rule-objects that for find an great solution for the strtoupper() usement.

Helpful links:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#flash-data